# Openerp Product Description

Tags: openerp-7

I have created a module for adding custom fields to product module.

I would like to know how to add those fields values into the product description, right now product description takes the name by default.

Answer (score 0):

use `_rec_name = "field_name"`

Click [HERE for more info](http://help.openerp.com/question/39188/how-to-add-field-value-as-header-in-breadcrumb/)